# Running python scripts consecutively in Crontab

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, web-scraping, cron

I am attempting to run my compilation of scripts one after another every minute.
**Example:** Assuming each script takes 2 seconds to finish:

start script 1 at 1:00, script 2 at 1:02, script 3 at 1:04, etc...

I assume it should look something like this

```
*/1 * * * * python script1.py && python script2.py && python script3.py
```

Comment: Your assumption should work as intended. Did you not try it? I'd only suggest to simplify your schedule to `* * * * *` which also fires every minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
* * * * * python /path/to/script1.py ; python /path/to/script2.py ; python /path/to/script3.py
```

Use `&&` if you want to run the second script only if the first script is successful (exit code is 0)

Use `;` if you want to always run the second script irrespective of first script's exit code

Always provide full path to your script in crontab

Comment: Correct.  Cron does not load the user's profile.  at, however, does load the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Your cron entry is fine.

You may want to create a wrapper script that calls all your scripts in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Your cron entry should work. However, you may notice that it may fail because you didn't specify the absolute paths for the scripts.

Comment: where can I view the log of the scripts? Or like the python shell of the scripts in terminal

Comment: If what you meant by `log` is the stdout of the script, then you need to redirect `stdout` to a log file. By default, you should receive a mail when the task got executed. Just type `mail` in your console to check your mails.